# PHPExcel GetCalculatedValue() return wrong value

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a .xlsx file with 6 sheet that I load with

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('./FINAL SEB.xlsx');
```

When I want to get a calculated value from a cell I get a wrong value.
This cell have a formula

```
(IF(COMPARATEUR!B6=20,EMPRUNT20ANS!F32,IF(COMPARATEUR!B6=25,EMPRUNT25ANS!F37,IF(COMPARATEUR!B6=15,EMPRUNT15ANS!F27,"Erreur années"))))-B35
```

In my PHP code I do

```
echo $worksheet->getCell('B38')->getCalculatedValue().'<br />';
```

When I debbuging I obtain

```
Formula Value is=(IF(COMPARATEUR!B6=20,EMPRUNT20ANS!F32,IF(COMPARATEUR!B6=25,EMPRUNTANS!F37,IF(COMPARATEUR!B6=15,EMPRUNT15ANS!F27,"Erreur années"))))-B35
Expected Value is 59045.580877165
Parser Stack :-
array (size=21)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'COMPARATEUR!B6' (length=14)
      'reference' => string 'COMPARATEUR!B6' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Value' (length=5)
      'value' => int 20
      'reference' => null
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Binary Operator' (length=15)
      'value' => string '=' (length=1)
      'reference' => null
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'EMPRUNT20ANS!F32' (length=16)
      'reference' => string 'EMPRUNT20ANS!F32' (length=16)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'COMPARATEUR!B6' (length=14)
      'reference' => string 'COMPARATEUR!B6' (length=14)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Value' (length=5)
      'value' => int 25
      'reference' => null
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Binary Operator' (length=15)
      'value' => string '=' (length=1)
      'reference' => null
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'EMPRUNTANS!F37' (length=14)
      'reference' => string 'EMPRUNTANS!F37' (length=14)
  8 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'COMPARATEUR!B6' (length=14)
      'reference' => string 'COMPARATEUR!B6' (length=14)
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Value' (length=5)
      'value' => int 15
      'reference' => null
  10 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Binary Operator' (length=15)
      'value' => string '=' (length=1)
      'reference' => null
  11 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'EMPRUNT15ANS!F27' (length=16)
      'reference' => string 'EMPRUNT15ANS!F27' (length=16)
  12 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Value' (length=5)
      'value' => string '"Erreur années"' (length=16)
      'reference' => null
  13 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Operand Count for Function IF()' (length=31)
      'value' => int 3
      'reference' => null
  14 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Function' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'IF(' (length=3)
      'reference' => null
  15 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Operand Count for Function IF()' (length=31)
      'value' => int 3
      'reference' => null
  16 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Function' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'IF(' (length=3)
      'reference' => null
  17 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Operand Count for Function IF()' (length=31)
      'value' => int 3
      'reference' => null
  18 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Function' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'IF(' (length=3)
      'reference' => null
  19 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Cell Reference' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'B35' (length=3)
      'reference' => string 'B35' (length=3)
  20 => 
    array (size=3)
      'type' => string 'Binary Operator' (length=15)
      'value' => string '-' (length=1)
      'reference' => null
Calculated Value is 9860500
Evaluation Log:
null
```

Can you help me please ?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the standardised testFormula() debugging code that I've posted here before to dump the trace you've shown, then this has changed in version 1.7.9 when the calculation engine was modified from a singleton to a multiton pattern to avoid problems when working with more than one workbook file at a time. An updated version of that code is shown below:

```
function testFormula($sheet,$cell) {
    $formulaValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getValue();
    echo 'Formula Value is' , $formulaValue , PHP_EOL;
    $expectedValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getOldCalculatedValue();
    echo 'Expected Value is '  , ((!is_null($expectedValue)) ? $expectedValue : 'UNKNOWN') , PHP_EOL;


    $calculate = false;
    try {
        $tokens = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
            $sheet->getParent()
        )->parseFormula(
            $formulaValue,
            $sheet->getCell($cell)
        );
        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        $calculate = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'PARSER ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

        echo 'Parser Stack :-' , PHP_EOL;
        print_r($tokens);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($calculate) {
        PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
            $sheet->getParent()
        )->getDebugLog()
        ->setWriteDebugLog(true);
        try {
            $cellValue = $sheet->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
            echo 'Calculated Value is ' , $cellValue , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(
                PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
                    $sheet->getParent()
                )->getDebugLog()
                ->getLog()
            );
            echo PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'CALCULATION ENGINE ERROR: ' , $e->getMessage() , PHP_EOL;

            echo 'Evaluation Log:' , PHP_EOL;
            print_r(
                PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance(
                    $sheet->getParent()
                )->debugLog
                ->getLog()
            );
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}


$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
testFormula($sheet,'A1');
```

Please try using the above to help diagnose the problem